# `geom_col()` renders x-axis scale (minimum wage data) incorrectly

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-col

I want to plot minimum wage data by state and year in a bar chart similar to [this plot in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_wage_in_the_United_States#/media/File:Minimum_wage_by_state_by_year.webp)

The data I used can be found [here](https://github.com/benzipperer/historicalminwage/releases/download/v1.4.0/mw_state_excel.zip). The following code block should render the desired output but the scale on the x-axis which has the minimum wage is incorrect (the highest min wage value should be $16.1 in DC).

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
bzipmw <- read_excel("mw_state_monthly.xlsx")
bzipmw %>% 
    transmute(year = year(lubridate::fast_strptime(gsub('m', '',`Monthly Date`), '%Y%m')), state = `State Abbreviation`, mw = pmax(`Monthly Federal Minimum`, `Monthly State Minimum`)) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    filter(year > 2008) %>% 
    ggplot(data = ., aes(mw, state, fill = year)) + geom_col()
```

[image: x-axis limits should be 0 to 20, with the longest bar being for DC at 16.1 but geom_col() renders 0 to 300. Other geoms like geom_point() don't have this issue]

I can't tell why `geom_col()` has this issue as other plots like `geom_point()` don't have this problem. Using `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,20))` causes most observations to get thrown out. Dividing `mw` by 10 doesn't help as the max should still be $16.1

ADDING MRE DATA:

```
bzip <- structure(list(year = c(2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 
2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 
2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 
2022, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2022, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 
2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 
2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 
2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 
2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 
2022, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 
2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2016, 
2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 
2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 
2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2021, 
2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2022, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022), state = c("AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", 
"AK", "AK", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AZ", 
"AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", 
"AZ", "AZ", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", 
"CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", 
"CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CT", "CT", 
"CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", 
"CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", 
"DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", 
"DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", 
"DE", "DE", "DE", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", 
"FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "GA", 
"GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", "GA", 
"GA", "GA", "GA", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", 
"HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", 
"IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "ID", 
"ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", "ID", 
"ID", "ID", "ID", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", 
"IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IL", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", 
"KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", 
"KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "LA", 
"LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", 
"LA", "LA", "LA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", 
"MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", 
"MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", "MD", 
"MD", "MD", "MD", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", 
"ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "ME", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", 
"MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", 
"MI", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", 
"MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", 
"MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MS", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", 
"MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "NC", "NC", 
"NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", 
"NC", "NC", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", 
"ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NH", 
"NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", "NH", 
"NH", "NH", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
"NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", 
"NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NM", "NV", 
"NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", 
"NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", 
"NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", 
"OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", 
"OH", "OH", "OH", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", 
"OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", 
"OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", 
"OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "OR", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", 
"PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "RI", 
"RI", "RI", "RI", "RI", "RI", "RI", "RI", "RI", "RI", "RI", "RI", 
"RI", "RI", "RI", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", 
"SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SC", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", 
"SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", 
"TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", 
"TN", "TN", "TN", "TN", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", 
"TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "UT", "UT", "UT", 
"UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", "UT", 
"UT", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", 
"VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", 
"VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "VT", "WA", "WA", 
"WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA", 
"WA", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", 
"WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WI", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", 
"WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WY", "WY", "WY", 
"WY", "WY", "WY", "WY", "WY", "WY", "WY", "WY", "WY", "WY", "WY", 
"WY"), mw = c(7.15000009536743, 7.25, 7.75, 7.75, 7.75, 7.75, 
7.75, 8.75, 9.75, 9.80000019073486, 9.84000015258789, 9.89000034332275, 
10.1899995803833, 10.3400001525879, 10.3400001525879, 6.55000019073486, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 8.5, 9.25, 10, 11, 11, 7.25, 7.25, 7.34999990463257, 
7.65000009536743, 7.80000019073486, 7.90000009536743, 8.05000019073486, 
8.05000019073486, 10, 10.5, 11, 12, 12.1499996185303, 12.8000001907349, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10.5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 7.28000020980835, 
7.25, 7.3600001335144, 7.6399998664856, 7.78000020980835, 8, 
8.22999954223633, 8.3100004196167, 9.30000019073486, 10.1999998092651, 
11.1000003814697, 12, 12.3199996948242, 12.5600004196167, 8, 
8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.69999980926514, 9.14999961853027, 9.60000038146973, 
10.1000003814697, 10.1000003814697, 10.1000003814697, 11, 11, 
12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 7.55000019073486, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 
8.25, 8.25, 9.5, 9.5, 10.5, 10.5, 11.5, 11.5, 12.5, 12.5, 13.25, 
13.25, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15.1999998092651, 15.1999998092651, 16.1000003814697, 
7.15000009536743, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.75, 7.75, 
8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.75, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 10.5, 7.21000003814697, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.30999994277954, 7.67000007629395, 7.78999996185303, 
7.92999982833862, 8.05000019073486, 8.05000019073486, 8.10000038146973, 
8.25, 8.46000003814697, 8.5600004196167, 8.5600004196167, 10, 
10, 11, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.75, 8.5, 9.25, 10.1000003814697, 10.1000003814697, 
10.1000003814697, 10.1000003814697, 10.1000003814697, 12, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.75, 8, 8, 8.25, 
8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 9.25, 10, 
11, 12, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12.75, 
13.5, 14.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 8, 8.25, 8.25, 8.75, 8.75, 9.25, 9.25, 10.1000003814697, 
10.1000003814697, 11, 11.75, 12.5, 7.25, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12.1499996185303, 12.75, 7.40000009536743, 
7.40000009536743, 7.40000009536743, 7.40000009536743, 7.40000009536743, 
7.40000009536743, 8.14999961853027, 8.14999961853027, 8.5, 8.89999961853027, 
9.25, 9.25, 9.44999980926514, 9.64999961853027, 9.64999961853027, 
9.86999988555908, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9.5, 9.5, 9.64999961853027, 9.85999965667725, 
10, 10.0799999237061, 10.3299999237061, 7.05000019073486, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.34999990463257, 7.5, 7.65000009536743, 7.65000009536743, 
7.69999980926514, 7.84999990463257, 8.60000038146973, 9.44999980926514, 
10.3000001907349, 11.1499996185303, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 6.90000009536743, 7.25, 7.25, 7.34999990463257, 7.65000009536743, 
7.80000019073486, 7.90000009536743, 8.05000019073486, 8.05000019073486, 
8.14999961853027, 8.30000019073486, 8.5, 8.64999961853027, 8.75, 
9.19999980926514, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.15000009536743, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 8.25, 8.38000011444092, 8.38000011444092, 
8.4399995803833, 8.60000038146973, 8.85000038146973, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
9, 10.5, 11.5, 6.84999990463257, 7.55000019073486, 7.55000019073486, 
8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 8.25, 
9, 9, 9.75, 9.75, 10.5, 7.15000009536743, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 8, 8.75, 9, 9.69999980926514, 10.3999996185303, 11.1000003814697, 
11.8000001907349, 12.5, 13.1999998092651, 7.30000019073486, 7.30000019073486, 
7.40000009536743, 7.69999980926514, 7.84999990463257, 7.94999980926514, 
8.10000038146973, 8.10000038146973, 8.14999961853027, 8.30000019073486, 
8.55000019073486, 8.69999980926514, 8.80000019073486, 9.30000019073486, 
6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 8.39999961853027, 8.39999961853027, 
8.5, 8.80000019073486, 8.94999980926514, 9.10000038146973, 9.25, 
9.25, 9.75, 9.75, 10.25, 10.25, 10.75, 10.75, 11.25, 11.25, 12, 
12, 12.75, 12.75, 13.5, 7.15000009536743, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.40000009536743, 
7.40000009536743, 7.40000009536743, 7.40000009536743, 7.75, 8, 
9, 9.60000038146973, 9.60000038146973, 10.1000003814697, 10.5, 
10.5, 11.5, 11.5, 12.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 8.5, 8.55000019073486, 
8.64999961853027, 8.85000038146973, 9.10000038146973, 9.30000019073486, 
9.44999980926514, 9.94999980926514, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 9.5, 11, 8.0600004196167, 
8.0600004196167, 8.14999961853027, 8.46000003814697, 8.60000038146973, 
8.72999954223633, 9.14999961853027, 9.60000038146973, 10, 10.5, 
10.7799997329712, 10.960000038147, 11.75, 12.5500001907349, 8.55000019073486, 
8.55000019073486, 8.67000007629395, 9.03999996185303, 9.1899995803833, 
9.31999969482422, 9.47000026702881, 9.47000026702881, 11, 11.5, 
12, 13.5, 13.960000038147, 14.4899997711182, 6.55000019073486, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 8, 8.75, 
8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 6.55000019073486, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
7.25)), row.names = c(NA, -795L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: `geom_col` stacks the bars by default, I think you might want `geom_col(position = 'identity')`. Basically, if you stack 10 years of a $10 on top of each other, you end up with a total of $100.

Comment: Alternatively, you can calculate the yearly increases (instead of the total wage) and plot those stacked.

Comment: I tried that (`geom_col(position = "identity")`), it fixed the axis but wouldn't show the `fill` for different years

Comment: The last bar is probably plotted on top, since it is plotted last. Use e.g. `... %>% arrange(desc(year)) %>%` to reverse the order before plotting. If you had a minimal reproducible example in your question I would write answer, but alas.

Comment: `arrange(desc(year))` worked! Thank you. I just saw your explanation for why `geom_col` is changing the axis. Thank you for explaining that as well. If you post any of the comments as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `bzipmw` posted as a structure in the second code chunk:

```
bzipmw %>% 
    transmute(year = year(lubridate::fast_strptime(gsub('m', '',`Monthly Date`), '%Y%m')), state = `State Abbreviation`, mw = pmax(`Monthly Federal Minimum`, `Monthly State Minimum`)) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    filter(year > 2008) %>% 
    arrange(desc(year)) %>%
    ggplot(data = ., aes(mw, state, fill = year)) + 
    geom_col(position = "identity")
```